# Short proof of correctness of Huffman algorithm

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory

I have to show the correctness (in terms of efficiency) of the Huffman-Algorithm in class. Given a source $$Q=\left(
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  a_1 & \ldots & a_N\\
  p_1 & \ldots & p_N\end{array}\right)$$
and treating the pairs of symbols $a_j$ and their probabilities $p_j$ as nodes, the huffman-algorithm, visually, connects the two nodes with least probability and treats the resulting tree as a new node with its own probability (the sum of the node's ones). It terminates in a binary tree that I can associate a binary code with. I have to prove that this code is optimal in the sense of having the least average codeword-length.

Every proof I found shows it via first developing the theory of greedy algorithms.

Is there an easy to formulate direct proof?

Comment: First you need to define exactly what the algorithm you're talking about is, and which correctness property of it you're aiming to prove. (Sure, we can imagine that it has to do with creating Huffman codes, but exactly which part of that process it is you call "the Huffman-Algorithm" is not clear without further specification).

Comment: To add to Henning's comment: Do you want to show that the coding is reversible (can be decoded)? Do you want to show that no other coding algorithm from a certain class of coding algorithms can be better? If so, which class of coding algorithms are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I want to show that no "single-symbol encoding" can do better (Is this the right term?). I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call an $n$-tuple $\mathbf a=(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\in\Bbb N_0^n$ of non-negative integers *admissible* if $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-a_i}\le1$.

For an $n$-tuple $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in[0,\infty)^n$ of non-negative reals and an admissible $n$-tuple $\mathbf a$ call $w_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf a):=\sum_{i=1}^nx_ia_i$ the *total code length* of $\mathbf a$ (with respect to $\mathbf x$).
Say $\mathbf a$ is *optimal* (with respect to $\mathbf x$) if it has minimal total code length with respect to $\mathbf x$.

**Theorem.** Let $n\ge 2$, $x_1,\ldots,x_{n}\in[0,\infty)$, and assume $x_i\ge \max\{x_1,x_2\}$ for all $i>2$.
Let the $(n-1)$-tuple  $(A,a_3,\ldots,a_{n})$ be optimal with respect to $(x_1+x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_{n})$.
Then $(A+1,A+1,a_3,\ldots,a_{n})$ is optimal with respect to $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n})$.

*Proof.*
Write $a_1:=a_2:=A+1$. First note that $\mathbf a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{n})$ is an admissible $n$-tuple because $2^{-(A+1)}+2^{-(A+1)}=2^{-A}$.

Let $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ be any admissible $n$-tuple.
We want to show $w_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf b)\ge w_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf a)$.
We may assume that $b_i\le b_j$ whenever $x_i>x_j$ (or else swapping $b_i\leftrightarrow b_j$ would produce a "better $\mathbf b$"). In particular, $b_i\le\min\{b_1,b_2\}$ for $i>2$.

Assume $b_1> b_2$. Then from $\sum_{i=1}^n2^{-b_i}\le1$, we obtain
$$2^{b_2-b_1}\le 2^{b_2}-\sum_{i=2}^n2^{b_2-b_i}.$$
The number on the right is an integer, hence $\ge 1$. It follows that the inequality remains true if we replace $b_1$ with $b_2$. At the same time this change to $\mathbf b$ decreases (or keeps) the total code length.
Similarly, if $b_2>b_1$, we can decrease $b_2$ without harm.
In other words, we may assume that $b_1=b_2$.
But then $(b_1-1,b_3,\ldots,b_n)$ is an admisible $(n-1)$-tuple and
$$\begin{align}w_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)}(b_1,b_1,b_3,\ldots,b_n) 
&=w_{(x_1+x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)}(b_1-1,b_3,\ldots,b_n) +x_1+x_2\\
&\ge w_{(x_1+x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)}(A,a_3,\ldots,a_n) +x_1+x_2\\
&=w_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)}(A+1,A+1,b_3,\ldots,b_n) 
\end{align}$$
$\square$